# Is total distance walked specific to a single Pokémon, or to a species of Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I walk a Squirtle (Squirtle A) for 10 km, then later select a different Squirtle (Squirtle B) as my buddy. Will it still show 10 km total walk distance, or will it be 0?

Has it always worked like this, or have there been changes since Buddy Pokémon have been in the game?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48577/discussion-on-question-by-tester101-is-total-distance-walked-specific-to-a-singl).

Comment: There is also a [Meta Discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12089/28182).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The total distance walked for a Pokemon is related to ***that specific Pokemon***.

That is, if you were to switch Squirtle A with 10km walked for Squirtle B with 5km walked, Squirtle B's total distance walked would appear as 5km walked, rather than 15km walked. This is how it has always worked.

Here are some images to prove it:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I didn't know it worked this way. Good thing I've always picked the same Pokemon when switching.

Comment: Upvoted because *PRAISE HELIX*